# Tomcat7 hangs during web app shutdown

Tags: hibernate, tomcat7

I am currently using tomcat - 7.0.52
Following is the thread dump when tomcat hangs. In this **pool-3-thread-1** is the thread which hangs but I am unable to debug which application code is starting it.
(If i press ctrl+c it shutdowns the tomcat but hangs when i use shutdown.bat)

[Tomcat Thread dump](http://pastebin.com/uAUvQD34)

Comment: I was unable to add thread dump in post (som formatting issue) so added it in pastbin :: http://pastebin.com/uAUvQD34

Comment: app is built using spring3+jersey2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue was related to Hibernate(4.0), as hibernate was unable to close ConnectionProvider (org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider).
To close ConnectionProvider manually --

```
    try{
            SessionFactoryImpl sf = (SessionFactoryImpl)factory;
            ConnectionProvider cp = sf.getConnectionProvider();
            if (Stoppable.class.isInstance(cp)) {
                ((Stoppable) cp).stop();
            } 
        }catch(Exception e){
            LOGGER.error("unable to stop connectionProvider",e);
        }
        this.factory.close();
    }
```